# Async/await in deeply nested method hierarchy

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

If you want to implement an async method deep in your call hierarchy, is the best practice (or the best suggested practice) is to make all the parents async?

I completely understand how the control flow moves in async methods, but most of the examples on the internet show just one method. I am interested in how to work with async/await in a deeply nested call hierarchy.

For example, what happens if you have:

```
void ControllerMethod() // Root method
{
     ServiceA_MethodOne();
}

// In another place in code
void ServiceA_MethodOne() 
{
     ServiceB_MethodOne();
}

// In another place in code
async Task<List<Product>> ServiceB_MethodOne()
{
     var data = await ctx.Products.ToListAsync();
     // some code here works with data.
}
```

It seems that essentially because you wanted to get Products asynchronously in one of your deeply nested children methods, all the parent methods now have to marked as async (I did not mark the parents as async in the above example on purpose for this example)

**Is this a correct assumption?**

Now, I know about `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which in effect can do this:

```
void ControllerMethod() // Root method
{
     ServiceA_MethodOne();
}

// In another place in code
void ServiceA_MethodOne() 
{
     ServiceB_MethodOne().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

// In another place in code
async Task<List<Product>> ServiceB_MethodOne()
{
     var data = await ctx.Products.ToListAsync();
     // some code here works with data.
}
```

This would be one way to basically "encapsulate" the async into one method. But in a lot of articles/tutorials this is frowned up (and there are valid but not yet understood technical explanations behind it)

So to summarize the question even more generally: when you use async/await on a method, does your whole parent caller hierarchy, starting from the direct parent that calls your method, all way up to the root method (whose caller you have no control over), be implemented as async methods?

Comment: You may want to give [Nesting async/await methods](//stackoverflow.com/q/11779375) a read, as it is a similar, but different question.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb is [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). It doesn't necessarily mean that you need to use the `async` keyword. You could also return the same task you've received.

```
void ControllerMethod() // Root method
{
     return ServiceA_MethodOne().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

// In another place in code
Task ServiceA_MethodOne() 
{
     return ServiceB_MethodOne();
}

// In another place in code
async Task<List<Product>> ServiceB_MethodOne()
{
     var data = await ctx.Products.ToListAsync();
     // some code here works with data.
}
```

It's also important trying to make your root method async if possible. ASP.NET MVC supports async actions. If you are writing a console app and you are using C# 7, you can also make your `Main` method async.

Comment: So lets say I am designing service methods, and I want Async and non-Async methods. What is the most performance efficient way to do so without repeating the logic? Should there be ServiceB_MethodOne() and ServiceB_MethodOneAsync() which just runs Task.Run(() => ServiceB_MethodOne())?

Comment: No, for async to work, or at least, have some utility, you need to do async all the way, if not, like @hardkoded said, if you need to call an async from a sync method, you have to use .GetAwaiter().GetResult();, which makes the async useless

Comment: @rekiem87: I dont think using GetAwaiter().GetResult() makes async useless. What if you need to load data for three models: Products, Users, Customers in parallel? Why cant you use Task.WaitAll(getProductsTask,getUsersTask,getCustomersTask) and then GetAwaiter().GetResult() on parent method to load them asynchronously?

Comment: You can use GetAwaiter().GetResult(). You have some examples in corefx https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a3021f143b762006a7e19ad11785ca0c3c454933/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/BaseAsyncStream.cs#L81

Comment: You should not use Task.Run to simulate async for a sync method as this will waste a threadpool thread or lead to thread congestion which may become an issue if you do this lots of times. Instead use `Task.FromResult(ServiceB_MethodOne)`.

Comment: @PurpleLizard, at the moment you call the ".GetResult" you are blocking your thread, which defeats the purpose of the async flow, the thread can not go to process other things because is waiting for the other tasks to end, if you need to wait for several parallel threads, while taking advantage of async, you should use "await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);"

Comment: @rekiem87: Yes, I am blocking my thread, but I am blocking it until 3 sets of data objects are loaded asynchronously. This is not blocking my thread until 3 sets of data objects are loaded sequentially.

Comment: I have never said that the threads would be executed sequentially, i just want to emphasize that it is not a recommended way to use async, since the reason for their creation was to avoid thread locks, and you are creating one. You can read more here https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html